# What are some interesting consequences of refuting the (generalized) continuum hypothesis?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory

I'm wondering if we have ever obtained interesting results or theories by refuting the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: The generalized continuum hypothesis is a very strong statement - it implies the axiom of choice, for example. So it's negation is pretty weak; it says that there is *some* cardinality $\mathfrak c$ such that there is a cardinal strictly in between $\mathfrak c$ and $2^{\mathfrak c}$, but it doesn't tell you anything about how large this counterexample to the generalized continuum hypothesis may be; it could be so large that it doesn't really have an impact on mathematics at the level of most real analysis and algebra, for example.

Comment: Just refuting the continuum hypothesis is enough. And we know of some interesting theories to do that (many forcing axioms, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You might find Freiling's axiom of symmetry to be of interest,

[Freiling's axiom of symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiling's_axiom_of_symmetry)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? As it stands, your "answer" is little more than a link to Wikipedia (which incidentally is broken).

Comment: Seeing how this is your sixth or seventh answer in the span of a few days, maybe it's time to register?

Comment: Note that this only applies to CH - the failure of the GCH doesn't imply anything about the symmetry axiom. (Of course this isn't meant as criticism - the OP mentions *both* the CH and GCH.)